# Stop user from accessing a Struts2 action directly?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, struts2

I have the following actions defined in my struts.xml

```
    <action name="Search" method="prepareLookUpvalues" class="com.mycompany.actions.FrSearchAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">search.layout</result>
    </action>

    <action name="List" class="com.mycompany.actions.FrSearchAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">results.layout</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">search.layout</result>
    </action>

    <action name="SearchDetails" class="com.mycompany.actions.FrSearchDetailsAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">details.layout</result>
    </action>

    <action name="Logoff" class="com.mycompany.actions.LogoffAction" >
        <result name="success" type="tiles">logoff.layout</result>
    </action>
```

Assuming that a user goes directly to my page home http://localhost:8080/fr/Search.action everything works OK, but it has been discovered hat some users are accessing http://localhost:8080/fr/List.action directly without first going to the search page which is causing problems.

When a user goes to the search page and enters criteria and submits, it is only then that the "List" action should be called via the struts form's action attribute.  I basically want to stop users from being able to access the "List", "SearchDetails", and "Logoff" actions directly unless those actions are invoked from my JSPs or code.

I'm new to maintaining/developing Struts2 applications and I haven't found clear answers to this.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There's a few details missing so the answer will be a bit vague, but the list action probably pulls values from a form submission to search?  Or pulls state from session?  Or...?

Anyways, however that may be stored, simply check and then redirect the user to Search if the state is not set as expected.

For details on doing redirects in struts2, see, for e.g. http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/actions/struts-2-redirect-action.shtml

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an elegant solution but you could try checking for the `referer` to see who called the action.  You action class will need to implement `ServletRequestAware`.

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
if (referrer.equals("http://localhost:8080/fr/Search.action")) {
// do the action
} else {
// handle unwanted access 
}
```

Remember that the referer is a client-controlled value and can be spoofed or removed.